# An Error Was Encountered. Unable to load the requested class: database

Tags: php, codeigniter

my login controller named logincontroller.php in application/controller/ directory is:

```
<?php

class LoginController extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('LoginModel');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->database();
} 


public function index(){
$this ->load ->view('login_view');
}

public function checklogin(){
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|callback_verifyUser');

    if($this -> form_validation ->run() == false){

        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }else{
             redirect('dashcontroller/index');

    }
}


public function verifyUser(){

    $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $password= $this -> input ->post('password');

    $this->load->model ('LoginModel');

    if($this->LoginModel->login($email, $password)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        $this ->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','wrong email or password');
        return false;
}

}
```

}
?>

*why is the error coming ?*

and i too make changes in the autoload.php for the database as `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

I am getting error: unable to load the requested class: database

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to some reasons.

1) `Somehow the filename of the library managed to chance causing CodeIgniter to be unable to find the file`

2) `Perhaps the file doesn't exist on the server and once again, CodeIgniter is unable to find it.`

3) `The filename may be different to that you are referring to in your code.`

Check the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996881/codeigniter-an-error-was-encountered-unable-to-load-the-requested-class-enc)